# How to add path for the file today.html in views.py and settings.py in django

Tags: python, django

I have a html file in my home directory named today.html

I have to load that file on a click of a link using django.

How to add the file path in views.py and settings.py files.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your home directory path to the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting in your project's settings.py file. Then when you try to render the template in your view, Django will be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you always have to keep your html files in template dir under django's project/root dir.

Than you have to configure template path in settings.py such as

```
from unipath import Path
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).ancestor(3) #ancestor value depends on number parent dir.

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
# Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
# Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
# Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
PROJECT_DIR.child('templates')
)
```

now you can access that html file by interating into urls.py such as

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

 urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'link_name_to_access^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="today.html")),
  )
```

**Note:**

*Using [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateviewhttps://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) you don't need to write specific view to render the required html.*

Comment: Is my answer helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

First copy the file today.html into your projects template folder.

Add the path in settings.py file. ie your project-path/your file-path(today.html).

Then create a function to open today.html file in views.py.

Now in urls.py file give the url.

ie. url(r'^today/$', 'your project-path.views.today', name='today'),

that's it